# Binding WPF Controls to EF Data

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework, binding

I was following some example tutorials on binding WPF simple controls to data using EF.

Specifically these tutorials were several years old using EF 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

In my case I am using Visual Studio 2012 and EF 5 though I am targeting .NET Runtime 4.0.

In one example "How Do I: Build a WPF Data Entry Form Using Entity Framework?":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dd776540.aspx

I tried to reproduce the tutorial (both in VB.NET and C#) using my environment and I got a problem with the following line of code:

```
Me.view = CType(customerSource.View, BindingListCollectionView)
```

This line throws the following runtime exception in my case:

"unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' to type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView'".

In another example of my own making (C# this time).

I have the following module level varaibles in a WPF code window:

```
private BindingListCollectionView customerView;
private NcrSupportEntities _context ;
private List<Customer> _list;
```

In the loaded event I initialise the variables:

```
_list = _context.Customers.ToList();
this.customerView = new BindingListCollectionView( new BindingList<Customer>(_list));
this.DataContext = customerView;
```

This time I get no runtime errors but the BindingListCollectionView methods do not work as intended.

For example if I want to add a new record the following code does not work as intended:

```
Customer customer = (Customer)customerView.AddNew();

customer.CustomerName = "<new>";
customer.Address = "";
this.customerView.CommitNew();

this.customerView.Refresh();
this.customerView.MoveCurrentToLast();
```

The UI controls display correctly but when I make updates to the bound fields and called the  Data Context "SaveChanges" method, the new record is not saved back to the database. Obviously the context is not keeping track of the changes made at the UI level.

To make this work I had to create a new customer object and add it to the Customers entities manually.

Neither does calling the BindingListCollectionView's RemoveAt method work for deleting a record. Instead I am also having to manually remove the record from the data context before calling "SaveChanges".

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Please do not answer back about how I should be using the MVVM paradigm, I am well aware of that, I just simply want to understand what is going on in my simple binding examples.

Comment: Your question is off topic for this website, as it is too broad in scope. This website is *not* a place to come to learn new languages... to use this website, *you* are required to have a certain level of knowledge and ask questions that you have about a specific programming problem. As such, I have voted to close this question. Please see the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page from the Stack Overflow Help Center for more information on this.

Comment: Sorry Sheridan, I see your point about my question being on the broad side. Though I do want to say in my defence, I am new to WPF but have been programming for over 25 years, i.e. I am not trying to learn a new language, just why a particular class (BindingListCollectionView) is not working as intended.

Comment: MarinosC, there's really no need to apologise... new users are not forced to read the advice from the Help Center. Perhaps you could edit your question to be more specifically about your `BindingListCollectionView` and then it would not be off topic and I would be happy to remove my close vote. Please read the [How do I ask a good question?](How do I ask a good question?) page from the Help Center to see how to do that best.